# Getting Parse PFUser: relational data

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, pfquery

I have a Parse class "Posts". "Posts" has a column, "user" which stores the user that made the post. It is of type Pointer<_User>.

I want to be able to retrieve the user, and then get an image stored in the User class.

So far I have:

```
PFQuery *postQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Post"];
[postQuery includeKey:@"user"];
PFObject *result = [postQuery getFirstObject];

if (result) {
    NSLog(@"successful query"); //Successful!
} else {
    NSLog(@"unsuccessful query");
}

PFUser *user = result[@"user"];
if (user) {
    NSLog(@"successful found user");
} else {
    NSLog(@"unsuccessful found user"); //Not successful
}
```

I successfully get "result", but I no "user". What am I missing?

Comment: Post or Posts? an empty result set would still be a successful query.

Comment: "Post". Using findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock, I confirmed that the query does return multiple objects and set is not empty.

Comment: log out the entire result.. what's in "user" ?

Comment: If I "NSLog(@"%@", [user username]);", the log reads (null).

Comment: This guy seems to have had the same problem - https://www.parse.com/questions/relational-query-from-user-class

Comment: I am able to successfully get all the other information from "result" (a Post) though, such as "title", "message", etc.

Comment: sorry, i meant log 'result'

Comment: {
    ACL = "<PFACL: 0x15e1bf70>";
    image = "<PFFile: 0x15e4f8e0>";
    location = "@lavics";
    locationCoordinates = "<PFGeoPoint: 0x15e4f8c0>";
    message = ..;
    thumbnail = "<PFFile: 0x15e4f270>";
}

Comment: When I comment out includeKey, it then also has the line: user = "<PFUser:sfAfp7FP1A>";

Comment: so, check that user object id... maybe it's not valid?

Comment: You nailed it. Thanks. The pointer was to a user that no longer existed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the User object pointed to had been deleted.  If a pointer column is included and it resolves to a non-existing object, it won't fail, but the object won't be fetched/included either.  You can probably detect this scenario after query w/ `includeKey` by checking for the `createdAt` field.